# Magento 2.0.7 After page refresh some js giving error?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.7, requirejs

Home page is loaded and but when I refresh the page some js gives error.
blocks are not loaded in home page.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).swMegamenu is not a function(anonymous  function) @ (index):227context.execCb @ require.js:1650Module.check @ require.js:866(anonymous function) @ require.js:1113(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ require.js:1156each @ require.js:57Module.emit @ require.js:1155Module.check @ require.js:917Module.enable @ require.js:1143Module.init @ require.js:774callGetModule @ require.js:1170context.completeLoad @ require.js:1564context.onScriptLoad @ require.js:1671
>       (index):247 
>       Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):247context.execCb @ require.js:1650Module.check @ require.js:866(anonymous function) @ require.js:1113(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ require.js:1156each @ require.js:57Module.emit @ require.js:1155Module.check @ require.js:917Module.enable @ require.js:1143Module.init @ require.js:774callGetModule @ require.js:1170context.completeLoad @ require.js:1564context.onScriptLoad @ require.js:1671
>       theme.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).stellar is not a function(anonymous function) @ theme.js:28fire @ jquery.js:3099self.add @ jquery.js:3145jQuery.fn.ready @ jquery.js:3379(anonymous function) @ theme.js:27context.execCb @ require.js:1650Module.check @ require.js:866(anonymous function) @ require.js:1113(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ require.js:1156each @ require.js:57Module.emit @ require.js:1155Module.check @ require.js:917Module.enable @ require.js:1143Module.init @ require.js:774callGetModule @ require.js:1170context.completeLoad @ require.js:1564context.onScriptLoad @ require.js:1671
>       dataPost.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function

Suggest me some solution.
this is my requirejs-config.js file

```
    (function(require){
    (function() {
    /**
    * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
    * See COPYING.txt for license details.
    */

     var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            checkoutBalance:    'Magento_Customer/js/checkout-balance',
            address:            'Magento_Customer/address',
            setPassword:        'Magento_Customer/set-password'
        }
    }
      };

      require.config(config);
       })();
         (function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    "waitSeconds": 0,
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "mageUtils": "mage/utils/main",
            "ko": "knockoutjs/knockout",
            "knockout": "knockoutjs/knockout"
        }
    },
    "shim": {
        "jquery/jquery-migrate": ["jquery"],
        "jquery/jquery.hashchange": ["jquery", "jquery/jquery-migrate"],
        "jquery/jstree/jquery.hotkeys": ["jquery"],
        "jquery/hover-intent": ["jquery"],
        "mage/adminhtml/backup": ["prototype"],
        "mage/captcha": ["prototype"],
        "mage/common": ["jquery"],
        "mage/new-gallery": ["jquery"],
        "mage/webapi": ["jquery"],
        "jquery/ui": ["jquery"],
        "MutationObserver": ["es6-collections"],
        "tinymce": {
            "exports": "tinymce"
        },
        "moment": {
            "exports": "moment"
        },
        "matchMedia": {
            "exports": "mediaCheck"
        },
        "jquery/jquery-storageapi": {
            "deps": ["jquery/jquery.cookie"]
        }
    },
    "paths": {
        "jquery/validate": "jquery/jquery.validate",
        "jquery/hover-intent": "jquery/jquery.hoverIntent",
        "jquery/file-uploader": "jquery/fileUploader/jquery.fileupload-fp",
        "jquery/jquery.hashchange": "jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange.min",
        "prototype": "legacy-build.min",
        "jquery/jquery-storageapi": "jquery/jquery.storageapi.min",
        "text": "mage/requirejs/text",
        "domReady": "requirejs/domReady",
        "tinymce": "tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src"
    },
    "deps": [
        "jquery/jquery-migrate"
    ]
};

require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $.noConflict();
});

require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            "rowBuilder":             "Magento_Theme/js/row-builder",
            "toggleAdvanced":         "mage/toggle",
            "translateInline":        "mage/translate-inline",
            "sticky":                 "mage/sticky",
            "tabs":                   "mage/tabs",
            "zoom":                   "mage/zoom",
            "collapsible":            "mage/collapsible",
            "dropdownDialog":         "mage/dropdown",
            "dropdown":               "mage/dropdowns",
            "accordion":              "mage/accordion",
            "loader":                 "mage/loader",
            "tooltip":                "mage/tooltip",
            "deletableItem":          "mage/deletable-item",
            "itemTable":              "mage/item-table",
            "fieldsetControls":       "mage/fieldset-controls",
            "fieldsetResetControl":   "mage/fieldset-controls",
            "redirectUrl":            "mage/redirect-url",
            "loaderAjax":             "mage/loader",
            "menu":                   "mage/menu",
            "popupWindow":            "mage/popup-window",
            "validation":             "mage/validation/validation",
            "welcome":                "Magento_Theme/js/view/welcome"
        }
    },
    paths: {
        "jquery/ui": "jquery/jquery-ui"
    },
    deps: [
        "jquery/jquery.mobile.custom",
        "js/responsive",
        "mage/common",
        "mage/dataPost",
        "js/theme",
        "mage/bootstrap"
    ]
};

require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            compareItems:           'Magento_Catalog/js/compare',
            compareList:            'Magento_Catalog/js/list',
            relatedProducts:        'Magento_Catalog/js/related-products',
            upsellProducts:         'Magento_Catalog/js/upsell-products',
            productListToolbarForm: 'Magento_Catalog/js/product/list/toolbar',
            catalogGallery:         'Magento_Catalog/js/gallery',
            priceBox:               'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box',
            priceOptionDate:        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-option-date',
            priceOptionFile:        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-option-file',
            priceOptions:           'Magento_Catalog/js/price-options',
            priceUtils:             'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
            catalogAddToCart:       'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
        }
    }
};

require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            addToCart: 'Magento_Msrp/js/msrp'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            quickSearch: 'Magento_Search/form-mini'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order': {
                'Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/model/place-order-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};

require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            requireCookie: 'Magento_Cookie/js/require-cookie',
            cookieNotices: 'Magento_Cookie/js/notices'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            creditCardType: 'Magento_Payment/cc-type'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            downloadable: 'Magento_Downloadable/downloadable'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            bundleOption:   'Magento_Bundle/bundle',
            priceBundle:    'Magento_Bundle/js/price-bundle',
            slide:          'Magento_Bundle/js/slide',
            productSummary: 'Magento_Bundle/js/product-summary'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            giftMessage:    'Magento_Sales/gift-message',
            ordersReturns:  'Magento_Sales/orders-returns'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            discountCode:           'Magento_Checkout/js/discount-codes',
            shoppingCart:           'Magento_Checkout/js/shopping-cart',
            regionUpdater:          'Magento_Checkout/js/region-updater',
            sidebar:                'Magento_Checkout/js/sidebar',
            checkoutLoader:         'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-loader',
            checkoutData:           'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
            proceedToCheckout:      'Magento_Checkout/js/proceed-to-checkout'
        }
    },
    deps: [
        "Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-loader"
    ]
};

require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            configurable: 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            multiShipping: 'Magento_Multishipping/js/multi-shipping',
            orderOverview: 'Magento_Multishipping/js/overview',
            payment: 'Magento_Multishipping/js/payment'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            pageCache:  'Magento_PageCache/js/page-cache'
        }
    }
};

require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            captcha: 'Magento_Captcha/captcha'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            orderReview:            'Magento_Paypal/order-review',
            paypalCheckout:         'Magento_Paypal/js/paypal-checkout'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            transparent:            'Magento_Payment/transparent'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
   (function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*eslint no-unused-vars: 0*/
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            loadPlayer: 'Magento_ProductVideo/js/load-player',
            fotoramaVideoEvents: 'Magento_ProductVideo/js/fotorama-add-video-events'
        }
    }
};

require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            recentlyViewedProducts: 'Magento_Reports/js/recently-viewed'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            transparent: 'Magento_Payment/transparent'
        }
    }
};

require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            catalogSearch: 'Magento_CatalogSearch/form-mini'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    paths: {
        'ui/template': 'Magento_Ui/templates'
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            uiElement:      'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/element',
            uiCollection:   'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/collection',
            uiComponent:    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/collection',
            uiClass:        'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/class',
            uiEvents:       'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/events',
            uiRegistry:     'Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry',
            uiLayout:       'Magento_Ui/js/core/renderer/layout'
        }
    }
};

require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            braintree:                  'https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js',
            braintreeDataJs:            'Magento_Braintree/js/cc-data',
            braintreeForm:              'Magento_Braintree/js/cc-form',
            braintreeEditForm:          'Magento_Braintree/js/cc-edit-form',
            braintreePayPalMinicart:    'Magento_Braintree/js/button/braintree-paypal-minicart',
            transparent:                'Magento_Payment/transparent'
        }
    }
};

require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            swatchRenderer: 'Magento_Swatches/js/SwatchRenderer'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            giftOptions:    'Magento_GiftMessage/gift-options',
            extraOptions:   'Magento_GiftMessage/extra-options'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            editTrigger:   'mage/edit-trigger',
            addClass:      'Magento_Translation/add-class'
        }
    },
    deps: [
        'mage/translate-inline'
    ]
};

require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            "taxToggle": "Magento_Weee/tax-toggle"
        }
    }
};

require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            wishlist:       'Magento_Wishlist/wishlist',
            addToWishlist:  'Magento_Wishlist/js/add-to-wishlist',
            wishlistSearch: 'Magento_Wishlist/js/search'
        }
    }
};
require.config(config);
})();



})(require);
```

Comment: please run command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: it is showing error sometime and sometime work?

Comment: @QaisarSatti yes sometimes it is working and some time it is not displaying static block suggest some solution

Comment: @Rakesh   after executing `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` got following error
`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Locale' not found in /var/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php on line 64`

Comment: show your requirejs-config.js file

Comment: @Rakesh plz find my updated question which includes requirejs-config.js

Comment: Is this your module requirejs-config.js file, Which js have you need to use in your module.

Comment: @Rakesh Yes this is requirejs-config.js

Answer (score 1):

i have faced the same issue solved it be adding the **setTimeout**

```
function slider2() {
  require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#owl-demo2").owlCarousel({

     navigation : false,
     slideSpeed : 300,
     paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem : true
      });
    });
    });

 }
    setTimeout(slider,1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

It beacause duplicated jQuery load in porto. I got the same problem when try to install Porto theme to Magento2. See more detail at http://magento2developer.com/blog/javascript-error-with-magento-porto-theme.html to fix the bug. It's will help you to solve this problem with other conflict Javascript bug in Magento 2 in the future. A lot of developer not write javascript in Magento 2